# How can I get app's resolution in android by command line or another app?

Tags: android

As title.
When a game is running, in **full screen**, how can I know it's resolution?
Can I type command in terminal emulator to get it, or another app?

Comment: Resolution of device screen doesn't change. You can get it from device's spec.

Comment: Well, I should provide more detail information.  

I install the same game into 2 different devices, and I saw **totally different** resolution game scene. I just know one is low, the other is high. But I don't know what resolution that game uses.  

So, I do know devices resolution is constant, how can I know game's resolution settings ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly, you should try this code. It returns screen dimensions in pixels

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);    

metrics.heightPixels;  // here is screen height
metrics.widthPixels;   // here is screen width
```

Notice that width and height values are switched to according screen orientation (in portrait w < h and in landscape orientation w > h)

Comment: Is there an app, or a command on terminal can retrieve this information? Should I had to write an app to get them?